# CV Style and Layout

Tags: moderncv

Can anyone tell me which syle the following CV is compiled from?

http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~umesh/bio/rajashekarCV.pdf

Comment: There is an e-mail-address on the CV. Why don't you just ask?

Comment: You could try to use this [software](http://latexifier.com/) which aims to retrieve LaTeX code from pdf output. I don't know if it works well or not.

Answer (score 5):

This is a duplication using the `article` class and some formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,includefoot]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{enumitem,fancyhdr,colortbl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,fancyhdr,colortbl}
\usepackage{lastpage,lmodern,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lastpage,lmodern,xcolor}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    \cellcolor{black!10}\large\strut #1
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\heading}[2][\relax]{\textbf{#2}\hfill#1\par\nobreak}
\newcommand{\pubheading}[1]{\par\bigskip\underline{\textbf{#1}}\par}
\newlist{subitems}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[subitems]{label={--},nosep}
\newlist{myreferences}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myreferences]{label={[\arabic*]},leftmargin=*}

\let\rmdefault\sfdefault% Default is sans serif
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No indent
\pagestyle{fancy}% Fancy page styl
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Footer rule
\fancyfoot[L]{Curriculum Vitae - My Name}% Left footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}% Right footer
\begin{document}
% Header
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
  \centering\LARGE My Name \\
  \centering\large \strut Curriculum Vitae \\[\jot]
  \hrule \mbox{}\\[\dimexpr-.4pt+\jot]
  \small My Address \hfill my@email.address \\
  \small My phone number \hfill http://my.website.url
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread titles out a tad...

\section{Education}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \heading[Dec~2005]{My PhD in Something or Another}
    The University of You Know Who, Here, THERE
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Dissertation title: \textit{Amazing things that one can do during procrastination (revisited)}
    \end{subitems}

  \item \heading[Aug~2000]{My MSc in Something or Another}
    The University of You Know Who, Here, THERE
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Thesis title: \textit{Amazing things that one can do during procrastination}
    \end{subitems}
\end{itemize}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \heading[Aug~2006 - present]{Sit-around-er}
    My home
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Watching television
      \item Sleep
      \item Eat
    \end{subitems}

  \item \heading[Jan~2006 - Jul~2006]{Assistant to the assistant regional manager}
    Dunder Mifflin
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Do as I am told
      \item Always at the ready
    \end{subitems}
\end{itemize}

\section{Publications}

\pubheading{Journal Articles}

\begin{myreferences}
  \item First item, Some title that is very long and spans more than a single line, 
    Chapter 1--10, pages 123--456, Academic Press, 2nd edition, 2009.

  \item Second item, Some title that is very long and spans more than a single line, 
    Chapter 1--10, pages 123--456, Academic Press, 2nd edition, 2009.
\end{myreferences}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer to you with just the pdf. My guess is this resume is not corresponding to a style but more likely to some little configuration of the standard article class.

But if your goal is to find a nice style to achieve the same kind of cv, you could look at [this style](http://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/logiciels/latex/cv.cls) which produces a [nice output](http://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/logiciels/latex/templates/cv2.ps.gz) ([.tex](http://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/logiciels/latex/templates/cv2.txt)) (sorry it's in French). Some modifications could make this cv look like the one you refer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find something rather similar in Sharelatex.com, it's called "Clean CV" there, but as Werner said, it's just an implementation of the article class.

```
% (c) 2002 Matthew Boedicker <mboedick@mboedick.org> (original author) http://mboedick.org
% (c) 2003-2007 David J. Grant <davidgrant-at-gmail.com> http://www.davidgrant.ca
% (c) 2008 Nathaniel Johnston <nathaniel@nathanieljohnston.com> http://www.nathanieljohnston.com
%
% (c) 2012 Scott Clark <sc932@cornell.edu> cam.cornell.edu/~sc932
%
%This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 2.5 License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/ or send a letter to Creative Commons, 543 Howard Street, 5th Floor, San Francisco, California, 94105, USA.

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}



%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
    }
    \newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
    \begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Large Your Name} & \textbf{\today} \\
Short description of you & E-mail \\
Adress & Homepage \\
\end{tabular*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{University Name}{City, Country}{BSc, MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

\begin{itemize}
    \resitem{Additional description nr 1}
    \resitem{Additional description nr 2}
\end{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{Other University Name}{City, Country}{BSc, MSc, PhD, or something else}{2004 - 2009}

\end{itemize}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Some important section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{enumerate}
 \item First item
 \item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
 \item First item
 \item Second item
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Awards, Grants \& Honours}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \vspace{-2pt}
    \begin{center}\begin{tabular*}{6.6in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nobel Prize \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2013}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Big grant \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2010-2013}\\
        \vphantom{E}
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}\vspace*{-16pt}


\end{document}
```

[image: cv]

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine built a CV similar, I made some updated to work in French an I have add a cover letter. 
The source code is [here](https://github.com/davebulaval/CV_template) .
Mine is in french, take a look at it.
[image]